# How to control multiple HTML classes using multiple radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I made a selectable card object using the radio button and I want to change its border color according to the radio button.

There's a code here that works well, but it doesn't look efficient because it looks up all the cards every time it runs. Is there any other solution?

(This code uses bootstrap.)

**html**

```
<div>
  <div class="card">
    <input type="radio" id="Select1" name="contact" value="Select1">
    <label for="Select1">Select1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <input type="radio" id="Select2" name="contact" value="Select2">
    <label for="Select2">Select2</label>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <input type="radio" id="Select3" name="contact" value="Select3">
    <label for="Select3">Select3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");
var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  var radio = radios[i];
  radio.addEventListener("change", border);
}

function border(e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    var radio = radios[i];
    var card = cards[i];
    if (radio.checked == true) {
      card.classList.add("border-primary");
    } else {
      card.classList.remove("border-primary");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with CSS? Is this in any way related to styling?

Comment: @NicoHaase OP is trying to toggle `border-primary` CSS class, hence the tag I guess

Comment: Would a pure css solution be ok for you?

Comment: _"but it doesn't look efficient because it looks up all the cards every time it runs"_ - unless you have thousands or more of those cards, there is probably no actual _need_ to optimize anything here. But if you want to write something more efficient for the "looks" of it - then don't loop over all cards, but only add the class to the current card, and only remove it specifically from the previous card you added it to.

Comment: You may store the currently selected radio in a variable and get the one that is set in a `change` from the event object `e`